# How do I verify an email address to a certain user in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, email-verification

I made a register form with a email address text field and such, so how do I verify that the email address belongs to the person. Could I make a code that is emailed to the user's email but how do I send emails in Xcode? Or is there some other way to do it with Firebase?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've created a user with their email and password, if there are no errors you send them a verification email.

```
import FirebaseAuth  

Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification
        {
            (error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            else
            {
                //CHECK INBOX FOR CONFIRMATION LINK
            }
        }
```